# Xcode 7 freezes/hangs after opening XIB file

Tags: xcode

I just create a new project with signal view or any with storyboard project.
When I open xib file or build project, the xcode hang forever.

Comment: same problem, impossible to open xib and storyboard files in xocde 7 beta 3, no useful message on the Apple forums, will file a bug report to Apple

Comment: Could you link the radar?